# How to check if a GPS coordinate is close to thousands of others efficiently?

Tags: python, gps

I have 11 millions of GPS coordinates to analyse, the efficiency is my major problem. The problem is the following:
I want to keep only 1 GPS coordinates (call it a node) per 50 meters radius around it. So the code is pretty simple, I have a set G and for every node in G I check if the one I want to add is too close to any other one. If it's too close (<50 meters) I don't add it. Otherwise I do add it.

The problem is that the set G is growing pretty fast and at the end to check if I want to add one node to the set I need to run a for loop over millions of elements...

Here is a simplified code for the Node class:

```
from geopy import distance

class Node: #a point on the map
    def __init__(self, lat, long): #lat and long in degree
        self.lat = lat
        self.long = long

    def distanceTo(self, otherNode):
        return distance.distance((self.lat, self.long), (otherNode.lat, otherNode.long)).km

    def equivalent(self, otherNode):
        return self.distanceTo(otherNode) < 0.05 #50 meters away
```

Here is the 'add' process:

```
currentNode = Node(lat, long)

alreadyIn = False
for n in graph:
    if n.equivalent(currentNode):
        alreadyIn = True
        break

#set of Nodes
if alreadyIn == False:
    G.add(currentNode)
```

This is not a problem of node clustering because I am not trying to detect any pattern in the dataset. I am just trying to group nodes inside a 50 meter radius.

I think the best would be to have a data structure that given coordinates return `True` or `False` if a similar node is in the set. However I can't figure out which one to use since I don't divide the environment in squares but in circles. (Yes a Node A can be equivalent to B and C without B and C being equivalent but I don't really mind...).

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Do you have to use Python?

Comment: If you don't need exact distances then you can take the differences in latitudes and longitudes, then use the sum of the squares as your metric `Δlatitude² + Δlongitude² < k(50m)²`, with `k` converting meters to degrees. For more accuracy, you can apply a correction to longitude based on the latitude.

Comment: Yes I need to use python. And the problem is not the accuracy @YiminRong , my metric is fine I think. The problem is the efficiency. I need to add the Nodes in the set faster without checking the millions of Nodes already in the set.

Comment: Also, if the input area is relatively small, i.e. can be approximated by  a flat surface, you can just define a region of say 5° ⨉ 5° divided into smaller areas, then bin your locations into them. Then you only need to consider the nearest 9 neighbours as candidates. Guess it would even work if your input area is large. Basically you'd be adding them to the approximate location as a first order approximation.

Comment: That sounds good but I don't know the size of the area. Let's say it's small anyway, I need to scale the number of bins as I read new nodes. I will try that with dictionary. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an object oriented approach is usually slower for calculations like this (though  more readable).

You could transform your latitude,longitude to cartesian x,y,z and create numpy arrays from your nodes and use scipy's very fast [cKDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html). It provides several methods for operations like this, in your case [`query_ball_point`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_ball_point.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query_ball_point) might be the correct one.

Comment: Nice, thank you for this. I didn't know that "high-dimensional nearest-neighbor querie is still a substantial open problem in computer science.".